# What would be the most logical way to reduce polycount of grass

Tags: particles

I have here a desk plant I modeled, and I made the hair particles a mesh. The polycount is 39K, its quite high if I wanted to import it into a game... I tried using decimate modifier but it said the object had to have 3 or more faces to be decimated. Please help! Is there another way to do this? how do i reduce the polycount of the grass?

[image]

Comment: Instead of individual blades of grass, use larger planes with textures of tufts of grass on each (with transparent backgrounds of course).

Comment: i don't want it to look fake or low res...

Comment: this is an asset i might be selling..

Comment: So model some individual blades *first* and use them to generate Diffuse and Normal maps for image planes. The grass will still appear to have depth because of the normal maps. Even if you only put 4 blades of grass per plane that's theoretically a 400% performance boost. The customers who buy it will appreciate it too. And if you plan on importing it into a game you'll probably want to pack *even more* blades per image plane. As you must know, poly count must be tamed in order for a game to perform acceptably. If it were me I'd make two versions, high and low poly, at different texture res.

Comment: how would i do this?

Comment: nevermind..thanks a ton Mentalist, that actually worked :)

Comment: Good! I'm glad you got it sorted. BTW I was just looking at [a related post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14063/2952) that has some good info about rendering normal maps.

Comment: also, is it possible to export the grass as an object?

Comment: Grass is a particle system. A particle system comprised of objects. You can export the objects in whatever format you like as long as they can be reinterpreted as particles in some other environment.

Comment: what else would you suggest instead of a texture? could you show me an example?

Comment: I'm not suggesting something else. You can have your grass particles be either image planes or grass blades. In the case of a game, image planes are the way to go.