# What is the best way to reduce polycount of the leaves

Tags: cycles-render-engine, add-on, sapling-addon

I have a small desk plant tree I modeled in Blender (using the **Tree Sapling Generator**) and it might be used in a game. It has a high polycount, so I've tried decimating it with the **Decimate** modifier but it gives me bad **UVs** and removes almost all the leaves. I don't want to use a texture, I would like individual leaves.

[image: Plant]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would be the most logical way to reduce polycount of grass](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98633/what-would-be-the-most-logical-way-to-reduce-polycount-of-grass)

Comment: No point in asking the same question twice. I think you should understand that poly counts and proper topology are not something you just randomly "paste" or blindly decimated on top of your object. They are an intrinsic part of your mesh. If you need low poly game assets model them accordingly from scratch, or at least make a decent high poly version and a low poly one you can bake your details to.

Comment: this is not a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

In the first image the faces are ***36K***
[image: Handle Type : Auto]

but when you switch from **Auto** to **Vector** in *Handle Type* you can see the number of Faces reduce to ***13K***[image: Handle Type : Vector]

you can see the difference
if it look like less ploy then you can increase the polygons of the branches in the **Branch Splitting** settings and modify the *Curve Resolution*
[image: Branch Splittion Stettings]