# How do I render a normal pass that is blue/pink instead of red/green?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, normals, render-passes

In my case, it's for an aesthetic purpose. I want to render out a version of my scene that has the blue/pink normal map look. Blender's standard Normal render pass seems to be red and green. I'm sure there is a functional/technical reason for this, but in my case I only want the pass for the look of it.

I would also prefer to do this with compositing nodes/rendering because I don't want to have to change all the materials in my scene individually just to fake the normals/blue pink look. I need both the combined render and the normal.

[image: I want this]

[image: this is what Blender gives me]

Comment: Not sure what settings you're using to bake, but blue/purple normal maps are Tangent Space normal maps, whereas multicolored like that are usually Object Space, or World Space ones... if that helps at all.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14044/render-entire-scene-normals